# How to make strict associations in Sails.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

Here are my two models that were generated using `sails generate api model_name`

**Guitar.js**

```
module.exports = {
schema: true,
attributes: {
    brand:{
        type: 'string',
        required: true
    },
    messages:{
        collection: 'message',
        via: 'guitar'
    }
}
};
```

**Message.js**

```
module.exports = {

    schema: true,

    attributes: {
        text:{
            type: 'string',
            required: true
        },
        author:{
            type: 'string',
            defaultsTo: 'Anonymous author'
        },
        guitar:{
            model: 'guitar',
            required: true
        }    
    }    
};
```

Basically, a `guitar` can have many `messages`.

The problem comes when I insert new messages into the DB:

`POST http://localhost:1337/message/`

With JSON content:

```
{
    "text": 4,
    "author": "33434",
    "guitar": null,
    "extra": "This attribute will be removed because schema: true"
}
```

If I send this, the server will throw an error because the message must have a `guitar`.

However, if I instead write `"guitar": 34`, and 34 is a guitar ID that doesn't exist, the `message` will be added, and `guitar` will be changed to `null`. Weird.

This seems to be a bug, or maybe it's the intended behaviour but with a NoSQL database in mind.

I need to make strict associations so that all data makes sense. I hope I don't have to create my own controller manually that handles this logic the way I want.

**Basically what I want is that Sails throws an error when the ID of the association doesn't exist.**

By the time I write this, I came up with a solution: Just configure this on the DB server (MySQL, etc) so that the foreign key must exist and then handle the error in Sails. But I'm not very happy with it since it depends on the DB server. I'd like this to work even with localDiskDb.

My other solution would be to actually write manually a controller and see what happens by using something like `Guitar.find(id).add(new_message)` (maybe it's wrong, I haven't tested this)

Comment: Yeah, I also noticed this behavior... I'm using mongo and I have to manually query relation model to check if the relation exists before saving "message" model... If you find better solution ping me pls :D

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about this but have you tried like this :

```
http://localhost:1337/message/create?text=4&author=3343&guitar=somerandomString
```